# what does the ActionMailer deliver command return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to figure out how to gracefully inform a user that an e-mail has not been sent from Rails.

The issue is this line of code:

```
OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
```

and what happens when the smtp server does not respond to the deliver command (smtp server is down, for instance). I've seen example code like:

```
@response_from_deliver = OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
```

but can find no documentation that says either this is a valid assignment or, if it is, what the various responses from an ActionMailer deliver might be.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 2):

You will get back the Mail::Message object type.  Apidock.com looks like it has some [good information on ActionMailer](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/mail).

```
#<Mail::Message:70225058423980, 
Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2014 12:06:05 -0600>, 
<From: info@socialrest.me>, 
<To: myemail@gmail.com>, 
<Message-ID: <52dd658d8f0f7_11643fde8d219160235e4@iMac.local.mail>>, 
<Subject: Welcome to My Site>, 
<Mime-Version: 1.0>, 
<Content-Type: text/html>, 
<Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable>>
```

Comment: As of 2022, The link you gave talks about the mail(...) method. The return value of this is stated to be of type Mail::Message. If I click on this, I get transferred to a page that states that Mail::Message is not defined in Rails 5.2.3. Weird. I do get a description of the Mail::Message object via the ActionMailer guide (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and a click there: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/Mail/Message.html. However, the methods deliver, deliver_now, deliver_later and all the rest of them are not mentioned there. WTF??

Comment: According to my research through debugging, the method mail(...) doesn't return a Mail::Message object at all (contrary to the info on the page mentioned above). Rather, it returns an ActionMailer::MessageDelivery.